# Why in my Android 5.0.1 bluetooth dialog is fullscreen while in android 6.0 it's displayed well

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, dialog

First screenshot is captured on my Asus Zenfone ZE500CL (Android 5.0.1)
[Screenshot 1 (Not OK)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzRtX.png)
Second screenshot is captured on my Samsung Galaxy S3 (Cyanogenmod, Android 6.0)
[Screenshot 2 (OK)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZwXP.png)
My code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
```